# Basement Steel Stud Framing with 1.5" Float

Tags: basement, studs, steel

How does one frame a basement with steel studs where 1.5" of float is required? I reached out to the inspector and he said "...use a bottom slip track deep enough to accommodate 1 ½” of float."

How does one secure the steel studs to the deep leg track and allow it to float at the same time? Do they dangle there?

Comment: I know nothing of steel stud framing, so I can't answer your question, but I'm sure someone here can. If all else fails (or, maybe to speed things along), ask the inspector, he seems willing to help, but just wasn't detailed enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one Googles "deep leg deflection track" one may see a photo like this one:
[image: Deep Leg Deflection Track]

There is a way to use this type of track to build a floating frame but I don't fully understand it and therefore don't want to spread misinformation.

Per FreeMan's suggestion I reached out to the inspector. He recommended using slotted track instead. This seems to be the more intuitive way to build a floating frame with steel.
[image: Slotted Track]

Comment: This is more of a comment and is very vague.   No one coming to this in the future would really understand your problem or solution to it.   You need pictures and material you will use and then maybe install pictures.

Comment: I thank you for posting the resolution, and I agree with @DMoore. The more info you can post about what the parts are that you used, the more you'll be able to help someone in the future, and that's what this site is all about.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Please be sure to click the check-mark as soon as the system will let you. That helps others to know this has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you for leaving comments advocating for a better answer. There is a wealth of information online when it comes to traditional wooden framing. The information on steel framing seems to be catching up right now thanks in part to the lumber shortage and availability of materials. That first image left me confused. Thankfully everything clicked when I saw the "slotted track". I'm assuming it'll be the same for others who were stumped in the same way that I was.